# Why is the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity not the other way around?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

The intuition often given for continuity is that as $x$ gets arbitrarily close to a point $c$, $f(x)$ gets close to $f(c)$. Just looking at this picture, why do we not arbitrarily bound $|x-c|$ and see if a corresponding bound can be placed on $|f(x) - f(c)|$? What is the reasoning behind doing this the other way around?

Worded differently, why do we not have for $\delta > 0$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$|x-c| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(c)|< \epsilon$$

Comment: Do you mean $|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$?

Comment: @ElliotG Yes thanks, typo on my part.

Comment: Since then the indicator function of the rationals will be continuous: choose $\varepsilon = 1267$ no matter what $\delta $ is given. In fact, any indicator function will be continuous. And many others.

Comment: it might interest you to note that the "forward direction" heuristic can indeed be made rigorous (for maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$): $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff whenever $x_n$ is a sequence converging to $x$, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$.

Comment: Do you agree with the definition of (function) limits? Continuity of a function $f$ at an accumulation point $a$ in its domain is equivalent to $\lim{x \to a} f(x)=f(a)$.

Comment: The idea of continuity is we don't want to see any sudden jumps, no matter how small the jump is.  So given any potential jump size $\epsilon$ near $c$, we can find a window around $c$ where the function won't jump that much.

Comment: @JairTaylor Ah so in essence the definition is saying if you can bound a "jump" then a continuous function should also bound the domain.

Comment: I think it would help you to review the definition of limits either for sequences and then for functions. Once you have understood these you will see why continuity is defined as it is.

Comment: @user That makes some sense, so in the case of continuity the limit of the sequence is $f(c)$ and the sequence itself are the points starting from $x$ and tending towards $c$?

Comment: @CBBAM I would put it just a little differently: You can bound the jumps (from $f(c)$) to be as small as you need by bounding the domain (around $c$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This definition would not be very useful. For example, any bounded function would be continuous. Take $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ where $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin\Bbb Q$. For any $c\in\Bbb R$ and any $\delta>0$, we have $|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(c)|\le 1$. So $f$ is continuous at every point.

Comment: I see, so was this definition introduced to patch any pathological cases or is there some other kind of motivation as well?

Comment: No, it's not a "patch", it's the definition. It says, we can approximate $f(c)$ by $f(x)$ as close as we like (within any distance $\varepsilon > 0$ we like) by taking points $x$ sufficiently close to $c$ (within some distance $\delta > 0$). The other way says something completely different: no matter how close $x$ is to $c$, $f(x)$ will be closer than some fixed (possibly large) distance away to $f(c)$. This condition could be called "local boundedness"; all you need is to make sure $f(x)$ doesn't blow out to $\pm \infty$ near $c$.

Comment: The step function would also be continuous. Any function which has a limit at $c$ and is defined at $c$ would be continuous. With this definition, it would be hard to come up with *any* function that isn't continuous.

Comment: Sorry I'm still trying to fully "accept" this definition and develop an intuition as to why it is defined as it is. Could you say the motivating factor behind this definition is to bound "jumps" in the image? Hence if the image can be bounded then so is the domain? This way we avoid infinite spikes?

Comment: I think I see your confusion. The goal is so that continuous functions don't "rip" or "break" the domain, so you want 'a small change in the domain' to map over to 'a small change in the image.' The the important part is that the change in the image is *arbitrarily* small. The values in the image are sort of... the ones making the demands, or maybe "the ones we have to worry about." Sorry if that is vague.

Comment: You might be interested in the notion of Lipshitz continuity, which says there is some constant $k$ such that $|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(c)|\le k|x-c|$. This captures your idea, but the important thing is that the value $k|x-c|$ is dependent on how close $x$ is to $c$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity

Comment: @ElliotG Ah this might have cured my confusion! Since we want small changes to correspond to small changes, and only the image can vary rapidly in small changes, that's why we focus on the image? To preserve the domain?